# Resolutions in a XNA Game

Tags: c#, xna, windows-runtime

I am going to play around with making an XNA game.

The windows store has two base resolutions it reccommends you support: 1024x768 and 1366x768

But after that there are no restrictions.

The common advice is to use a ViewBox that will scale your content for you.

But an XNA game does not have a viewbox.  It has a draw method where you render your content.

What is the common way for Games (XNA or DirectX) to adapt to different resolutions?

I would rather not have to make images for each and evey resolution out there.  It would be a lot of work and I am bound to miss some.

Is there a better way?

Comment: By the way, you can not make windows store apps using XNA. ([source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bobfamiliar/archive/2012/08/01/windows-8-xna-and-monogame-part-1-overview.aspx))

Comment: @GameScripting - But MonoGame (An Open Implementation of XNA) does support Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 RT.  Will Microsoft not allow those in the Windows Store? (http://monogame.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I think they'll allow it, XNA by microsoft just isn't *supported* (technically).

Answer (score 6):

`GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width`and`.Height` will give you the current desktop resolution.

Then you can update `Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport` variables to use these settings.

The above code usually goes in Game1.cs constructor

The link provided then documents one technique that makes your sprites, backgrounds etc look correct independently of the resolution(the theory should be sound if the code is not 100% up to date)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447674%28v=xnagamestudio.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are two different approachs I read [in a tutorial](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Resolution_independency.php):

- Resize everything to the new viewport (even with changing aspect ratio)
- Just draw more surroundings around

Of course you can mix both: Resize everything as long as it can still be in the same aspect ratio (e.g. 4:3 or 16:9) and then show more or less background / surroundings.

You can also decide to display black content instead of the more surroundings, if it is important for everyone to have exactly the same sight (e.g. due to fairness), but in such a case it might be a better idea to use fog of war to reduce sight.